# wbart (BART) returns negative y although I don't have negative values

Tags: bart

```
Code: 

data <- data
x <-as.matrix(data[, c(1,2,3,4)])
y <- as.matrix(data[, c(5)])
head(cbind(x,y))

#BART
set.seed(99)
nd <-50
burn <-200
post <-wbart(x,y, nskip = burn, ndpost = nd)
```

`results`
Results:

> post <-wbart(x,y, nskip = burn, ndpost = nd)
> *****Into main of wbart
> *****Data:
> data:n,p,np: 365, 4, 0
> y1,yn: -239.336986, -172.336986
> x1,x[n*p]: 480.000000, 2.000000
> *****Number of Trees: 200
> *****Number of Cut Points: 100 ... 71
> *****burn and ndpost: 10, 5
> *****Prior:beta,alpha,tau,nu,lambda: 2.000000,0.950000,10.553569,3.000000,0.000000
> *****sigma: 0.000000
> *****w (weights): 1.000000 ... 1.000000
> *****Dirichlet:sparse,theta,omega,a,b,rho,augment: 0,0,1,0.5,1,4,0
> *****nkeeptrain,nkeeptest,nkeeptestme,nkeeptreedraws: 5,5,5,5
> *****printevery: 100
> *****skiptr,skipte,skipteme,skiptreedraws: 1,1,1,1

MCMC
done 0 (out of 15)
time: 0s
check counts
trcnt,tecnt,temecnt,treedrawscnt: 5,0,0,5

```
Why am I getting y1,yn: -239.336986, -172.336986 When I don't have negative values. 


I know I can get negative values with BART as part of the data transformation but my lowest value in the data set is: 98 and the highest 695. 

Thanks in advance. 

I shouldn't get negative values at all.
```